# Cannot get MariaDB to start

Tags: mariadb

I've been away and one of my databases became a massive size that MariaDB had crashed and I cannot get it to restart. I have tried moving the path /var/lib/ and restart to no avail. I am trying to find messages in /var/log/mysql/ and /var/log but there are no error messages to give me a clue.

Can anyone offer some solutions?

MariaDB: 10.0.12
Debian 7.6.

Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. Rebooting Debian resolved the issue.

Comment: MariaDB error log is in the data directory. Just read its final lines to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check for error messages in the syslog. Mariadb 10.0.* send tehm there if you do not change the /etc/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf and comment the 2 lines: skip_error_log and syslog